I am trying to get a total count and a subtotal split by another Id value
This is a WPF application that is backed up a local SQLite database. I am parsing a couple hundred text files at to pull error data.
I am new to SQL am trying to build a query to count the total occurrence of error codes as well as the sub total by each 'Tool Id'
The Error Codes and Tool Ids all input from the text files and are not known at runtime. I am currently putting the query results into a WPF datatable to display.
Here is what my database looks like.



Db Id
Lot Id
Tool Id
Error Code
Error Title




1
B410D9Y0
CNP501
5000-503-500-BB8
Measurement error


2
B411DANA
CNP501
5000-503-500-BB8
Measurement error


3
B414DF40
CNP502
5000-503-500-BB8
Measurement error


4
B414DF40
CNP502
5000-503-500-BB8
Measurement error


5
B414DF40
CNP502
5000-503-500-BB8
Measurement error


6
B414DFW0
CNP502
1000-320-3FC-3F7
Main sequence


7
B414DFW0
CNP502
1000-0-4-0
Sequence Paused by Error


8
B414DFW0
CNP502
5000-503-500-BB8
Measurement error


9
B414DFW0
CNP502
5000-503-500-BB8
Measurement error


10
B414DFW0
CNP502
5000-503-500-BB8
Measurement error


11
B414DFW0
CNP502
5000-503-500-BB8
Measurement error



I have queries to get the individual pieces.
SELECT [Error Code], COUNT(*) AS Total 
FROM ErrorEntries 
GROUP BY [Error Code]

This gives me the error code totals



Error Code
Total




1000-0-4-0
1


1000-320-3FC-3F7
1


5000-503-500-BB8
9



SELECT [Tool Id], [Error Code], COUNT(*) AS Total 
FROM ErrorEntries 
GROUP BY [Tool Id], [Error Code]

This gives me the totals split by Tool Id



Tool Id
Error Code
Total




CNP501
5000-503-500-BB8
2


CNP502
1000-0-4-0
1


CNP502
1000-320-3FC-3F7
1


CNP502
5000-503-500-BB8
7



But I need them combined so the tool totals are displayed next to the error code totals



Error Code
Total
CNP501
CNP502




1000-0-4-0
1
0
1


1000-320-3FC-3F7
1
0
1


5000-503-500-BB8
9
2
7



Thanks to CDnX for pointing out I was looking for a pivot table.
This is the query I found that worked to build the layout I needed.
SELECT ErrorCode, 
  COUNT(*) AS Total,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN ToolId = "CNP501" THEN 1 ELSE null end) AS CNP501,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN ToolId = "CNP502" THEN 1 ELSE null end) AS CNP502
FROM ErrorEntries
GROUP BY ErrorCode
ORDER BY ErrorCode;

After researching I realized the part of my problem was that I would need to dynamically build the the SQLite query since the tool ids are not known.
To accomplish this I had to get all the toolIds from the database into a string array and build a COUNT string for each one.
Here is the string building function I used.
// Build a 'COUNT()' string for each toolId as toolId
public static string ToolErrorCountStringBuilder(string[] toolIds)
{
    string[] toolErrorCountStrings = new string[toolIds.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < toolIds.Length; i++)
    {
        toolErrorCountStrings[i] = $"COUNT(CASE WHEN [Tool Id] = '{toolIds[i]}' THEN 1 ELSE null end) as {toolIds[i]}";

        // All lines need a comma except the last one 
        if (i != toolIds.Length - 1)
        {
            toolErrorCountStrings[i] += ",";
        } else                 {
            toolErrorCountStrings[i] += " ";
        }
    }

    return string.Join("",toolErrorCountStrings);
}

That full string was then put into the full SQLite query to fill the datatable.
public static void GetErrorCount(DataTable dt)
{
    using (var connection = GetConnection())
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT ErrorCode," +
                                  "COUNT(*) AS Total," +
                                  ToolErrorCountStringBuilder(GetDistinctToolIds()) +
                                  "FROM ErrorEntries " +
                                  "GROUP BY ErrorCode " +
                                  "ORDER BY ErrorCode";
            using (var adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command))
            {
                dt.Clear();
                adapter.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
    }
}


Just as a sanity check here, how many ToolIds are you dealing with. For instance, if you have 200 ToolIDs that is going to be a "result table" with 202 columns - not very easy to use for all practical purposes since it will be so extremely wide.

There are 6 tools currently but there will be up to ~20

You're trying to make pivot table.
Sqlite doesn't support automatic pivot table functionality, so you should do it manually.
You can get your example result with query like this;
SELECT
  ErrorCode,
  COUNT(*) AS Total,
  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE ToolId = 'CNP501') AS CNP501,
  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE ToolId = 'CNP502') AS CNP502
FROM
  ErrorEntries
GROUP BY
  ErrorCode

Column names are CamelCased to avoid whitespace in between.
If your target value list of ToolId is large or need to be dynamic, this approach is very inefficient and sometimes impossible. There's sqlite extension named pivot_vtab, so you can try using it.

Thanks, this is most of what I was looking for. Although, the FILTER clause is not working for me. This variation of the count line ended up working.
COUNT(CASE WHEN ToolId = "CNP501" THEN 1 ELSE null end) CNP501

As you can check on SQLite Release History, FILTER clause support has been added on SQLite 3.30.0. If your SQLite version is lower than that, it would not work. Fortunately, COUNT(CASE...) is supported not only on the older version of SQLite, but also on the almost every other DBMSs unlike FILTER because FILTER clause is defined as optional feature on SQL:2003 standard.
